# Numpy conditional multiply data in array (if true multiply A, false multiply B)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a large array of value 0~255. I wanted every element in this array that is higher than 100 got multiplied by 1.2, otherwise, got multiplied by 0.8.

It sounded simple but I could not find anyway other than iterate through all the variable and multiply it one by one.

Comment: Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: ```np.multiply(a, np.where(a > 100, 1.2, .8))```

Answer (score 8):

If `arr` is your array, then this should work:

```
arr[arr > 100] *= 1.2
arr[arr <= 100] *= 0.8
```

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, this could have the undesired effect of the first step affecting what is done in the second step, so we should instead do something like

```py
# first get the indexes we of the elements we want to change
gt_idx = arr > 100
le_idx = arr <= 100
# then update the array
arr[gt_idx] *= 1.2
arr[le_idx] *= 0.8
```

Comment: I once tried this fancy indexing approach, but the criterion I mentioned is just an example. On some use-case I intended like if 1.2 were 0.2 instead, the first operation will subsequently make the value eligible for computing in the second operation as well.

Comment: @5argon In this case you can save the result of your comparison before altering the array. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have a faster implementation than `np.where`, also a one-liner improvement on @vindvaki:

```
a*=((a>100)*1.2+(a<100)*0.8)
```

With it you don't need to make an extra function call, and you can also add arbitrarily many modifiers using boolean logic multipliers. This one-liner will save you some computational time if your arrays get big (like 10**8 big).

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` is the answer. I spend time messing with `np.place` without knowing its existence.